# how to disable user interaction for slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I implement jQuery UI Slider but i control this slider with javascript and i won't to block user interaction. I use as handle `a.ui.slider-handle`.

I have tried this:

```
 $('a.ui-slider-handle').unbind()
```

, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post your HTML and Jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

To disable user interaction and keep slider enabled, use:

```
$('#slider').slider();
$('#slider.ui-slider, #slider ui-slider-handler').off();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pwXR6/2/

Comment: My problem is not make slider disable but to disable user interaction and make slider enabled.